# Median calculation in ActionScript 3

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a number array and I'd like to calculate the median.
When the array is odd, the calculation is OK, when it's even strange number comes up.

```
private var numbers:String = "2,5,3,4,6,1";
private var array:Array = numbers.split(",");

private function getMedian(array:Array):Number {
 var sortnums:Array = array.sort(Array.NUMERIC);
 var length:Number = sortnums.length;
 var mid1:Number; var mid2:Number; var median:Number;

 if(length % 2 == 0){
     mid1 = length / 2; trace("mid1: "+mid1);
 mid2= ((length - 1) / 2)-0.5; trace("mid2: "+mid2);
 trace ("mid1: "+sortnums[mid1]+", mid2: "+sortnums[mid2]);
 median = (sortnums[mid1] + sortnums[mid2]) / 2;
 }else{
 mid1 = (length / 2)-0.5
 median = sortnums[mid1]
 }
 trace (median);
 return median;
}
```

The result is 21.5, but should be 3.5

mid1 and mid2 are a position in the array.

Could somebody help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this (for tidyness):

```
function getMedian(plug:Array):Number
{
    // Even length.
    if(plug.length % 2 == 0)
    {
        var a:Number = plug[int(plug.length / 2) - 1];
        var b:Number = plug[int(plug.length / 2)];

        return (a + b) / 2;
    }

    // Odd length.
    return plug[int(plug.length / 2)];
}


// Tests.
trace(getMedian([2,5,3,4,6,1])); // 3.5
trace(getMedian([2,5,3,4,6])); // 3
```

By the way, I'm fairly certain your code is working fine, the problem is that you're doing this as a string concatenation rather than a number sum here:

```
median = (sortnums[mid1] + sortnums[mid2]) / 2;
```

Meaning you're literally adding the *string* `1.5` onto `2` and getting `21.5` rather than `3.5`.

Try amending your code so it reads like so:

```
median = (Number(sortnums[mid1]) + Number(sortnums[mid2])) / 2;
```

Comment: On a complete side note, you should sanitize and convert your string values to numeric ones, prior you do your calculations.

Comment: @joncys Yup, that is of course preferred. My initial function takes an array that already contains numbers to do this.

Comment: [at] Marty — That comment had to go as a comment to OP's post, not your answer, my mistake. (How do you quote names with spaces anyway?!)

Comment: @joncys Think you just truncate the spaces i.e. MartyWallace :)